# Skip Spot Bugs stack traces when features require ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL

Tags: java, spotbugs, unsupportedoperation, java-14, preview-feature

I'm using **spotbugs-maven-plugin 4.0.0** (+ **spotbugs** 4.0.2 dependency).

The problem is that it cannot recognize Java 14 **records**.

Every time when it finds a record or a class that uses that record, it prints a long stacktrace.

```
[INFO] >>> spotbugs-maven-plugin:4.0.0:check (default) > :spotbugs @ core >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spotbugs-maven-plugin:4.0.0:spotbugs (spotbugs) @ core ---
[INFO] Fork Value is true
     [java] The following errors occurred during analysis:
     [java]   Unable to get XClass for com/something/MyRecord
     [java]     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitRecordComponentExperimental(ClassVisitor.java:304)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readRecordComponent(ClassReader.java:929)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:704)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:552)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:736)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:79)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:685)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:975)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:909)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:252)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs.runMain(FindBugs.java:395)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.main(FindBugs2.java:1231)
     [java]   Couldn't get class info for com/something/MyRecord
     [java]     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitRecordComponentExperimental(ClassVisitor.java:304)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readRecordComponent(ClassReader.java:929)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:704)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:552)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:736)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:79)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:685)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:975)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:909)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:252)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs.runMain(FindBugs.java:395)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.main(FindBugs2.java:1231)
     [java]   Exception analyzing com.something.MyClassThatUsesMyRecord using detector edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.CalledMethods
     [java]     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitRecordComponentExperimental(ClassVisitor.java:304)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readRecordComponent(ClassReader.java:929)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:704)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
     [java]       At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:552)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:736)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:79)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:685)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:975)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:909)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:252)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs.runMain(FindBugs.java:395)
     [java]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.main(FindBugs2.java:1231)
     ...

[INFO] Done SpotBugs Analysis....
```

How can I get rid of these detailed exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the plugin's [latest release](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-maven-plugin/releases/tag/spotbugs-maven-plugin-4.0.0) read the support through JDK-15, the ASM support for **preview features** require 8.0+ version while the library is still on `7.3.1`.

That said, the [changes to their deployable branch](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-maven-plugin/compare/spotbugs-maven-plugin-4.0.0...spotbugs#files_bucket) should fix this. Specifically the difference in:

```
- <asm.version>7.3.1</asm.version>
+ <asm.version>8.0.1</asm.version>
```

So just wait for the next version while requesting them to release soon. :)